# Best way to pass a model to a new ViewDataDictionary in MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to migrate my current MVC5 project over to MVC6 but have hit a minor snag around the new namespaces/methods, primarily with `ViewDataDictionary`. In MVC5 you could easily initiate a `new ViewDataDictionary` by just passing your model like so...

```
PartialViewResult pv = new PartialViewResult();
pv.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
```

...but there doesn't seem to be any overloads for this in MVC6 without actually having a ViewDataDictionary object available.

So I suppose my question is, what is the best method to create a new ViewDataDictionary from scratch? I can see the following overload but I'm unable to find any examples on how to use it.

```
public ViewDataDictionary(IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, ModelStateDictionary modelState);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a new `ViewDataDictionary` and then assign its model property.

- The new framework does that, the [`ViewDataDictionaryControllerPropertyActivator`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/ViewDataDictionaryControllerPropertyActivator.cs) creates the ViewData. The model model property is set when you use one of the helper methods in the Controller like [`View`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs), as in `return View(model)`

You will just need to get an `IModelMetadataProvider` which you can either get using DI in your controller or via the `HttpContext.ApplicationServices` service locator.

```
public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var modelMetadataProvider = this.Context.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();
    var viewDataDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary<FooModel>(modelMetadataProvider, new ModelStateDictionary());
    viewDataDictionary.Model = new FooModel();

    ...        

}
```

Maybe you could provide an extension method:

```
public static ViewDataDictionary<T> CreateViewDataDictionary<T>(this HttpContext httpContext, T model)
{
    var modelMetadataProvider = httpContext.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();
    return new ViewDataDictionary<T>(modelMetadataProvider, new ModelStateDictionary())
    {
        Model = model
    };
}

public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var viewDataDictionary = this.Context.CreateViewDataDictionary(new FooModel());

    ...

}
```